# Как правильно строить архитектуру файлов для бота aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram, telegram

Делаю большого **телеграм бота**, но уткнулся в то, что код стал крайне **большим**.

Видел как люди отдельные **части кода** распределяли по **разным файлам**.
**Как это правильно организовать?**

Можете дать ссылку на видео/туториал

Answer (score 2):

Лично я делаю условно по паттерну MVC (хотя трудно назвать такую реализацию здесь реальным паттерном, но отталкиваюсь именно от него), то есть выстраивать архитектуру на основе `model`:`view`:`controller`.

В `app.py` находятся все статические переменные, например экземпляр бота, экземпляр диспетчера, экземпляр `app`-объекта, если вы используете `Flask`/`FastAPI` и `webhooks`. Сюда в принципе можно выносить и другие статические данные.

В `controller.py` находится вся логика, возможно распределена по своим классам. Иногда можно создавать другие зависимые файлы - к ним нужно только подключать экземпляры с файла `app.py`, и все - можно строить уже логику по разным файлам, как вы задали в вопросе. Можно конечно прикрутить и наследование, но ООП для ботов - спорная тема.

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ: чтобы не получать ошибки о частично инициализируемых объектах - нужно в каждом файле всегда **первым** делать импорт из файла `app.py`, так как некоторые декораторы ссылаются на эти объекты из этого файла (`app.py`), что в общем-то ломает основную логику работы.

В `models.py` должны быть созданы модели базы данных, если вы знакомы с ORM, в противном случае можно просто создать функцию, которая отвечает за соединение к базе данных.

В файле `main.py` создается точка входа. Можно также создать режим `DEBUG` - очень удобное применение, если часто вносятся данные в код. При этом логика работы такова: если `DEBUG` это `TRUE`, тогда запускать метод `executor.start_polling(dp)`, в противном случае запуск веб-сервера. Я использую для своих целей `uvicorn`.

В файле `config.py` выносятся все основные конфиденциальные данные. Еще как вариант - можно их спрятать в переменных среды.

При этом, чтобы строить такую архитектуру - каждая задача должна быть распределена в свою функцию. Если отталкиваться от паттерна, это нужно для того, если в каком-то файле будет отключена функция или убран вызов какой-то функции - она не сломает всю логику бота, то есть каждый файл должен быть независимым (условно) друг от друга.